# Bison type clash on C++ subclasses

Tags: c++, bison

So I'm getting type clashes in bison, of the form

```
warning: type clash on default action: <stmt> != <expr>
```

because I have a production like

```
%type <stmt> Stmt
%type <expr> Expr
...
Stmt : Expr    /* empty */
     | Otherstuff {do other stuff.....}
     ;
```

I was wondering if there was a way to get rid of these errors, because Expr is a subclass of Stmt (I'm using c++), but has extra functions so just putting in

```
%type <stmt> Stmt Expr
```

won't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easy way is:

```
Stmt : Expr         {$$ =  $1;} // This is the same as default action
```

Comment: This seemed to work well, but why does this not cause a type clash when the default action does?

Comment: Because `bison` does not know anything about C++ types. It can only work with the type information it has. But when you are explicit `bison` assumes you know what you are doing and passes on responsibility of checking to the compiler.